# Is copy/move elision allowed to make a program using deleted functions well-formed?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, copy-elision

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Thing
{
    Thing(void)                       {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
    Thing(Thing const &)              = delete;
    Thing(Thing &&)                   = delete;
    Thing & operator =(Thing const &) = delete;
    Thing & operator =(Thing &&)      = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Thing thing{Thing{}};
}
```

I expect `Thing thing{Thing{}};` statement to mean construction of temporary object of `Thing` class using default constructor and construction of `thing` object of `Thing` class using move constructor with just created temporary object as an argument. And I expect that this program to be considered ill-formed because it contains an invocation of deleted move constructor, even though it can be potentially elided. The **class.copy.elision** section of standard seems to demand this as well:

> the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided

The [Wording for guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html) does not seem to allow it either.

However gcc 7.2 (and clang 4 as well, but not VS2017 which [still does not support guaranteed copy elision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance)) will [compile this code just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14daef7a5ebbf6da) eliding move constructor call.

Which behavior would be correct in this case?

Comment: Why would you expect a temporary here, but not in `Thing thing{f()};` where `f()` returns a `Thing` ?

Comment: Also, I suspect that "accessible" means "not private".

Comment: @BoPersson No, it also works with private constructors.

Comment: @BoPersson I would expect `Thing thing{f()};` to mean invocation of move constructor with a temporary returned by `f()` call a an argument. Which will be hopefully elided avoiding overhead of creating temporary.

Comment: _The Wording for guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories does not seem to allow it either_ It does, but surprisingly few people understand **how** (or they don't hurry to answer). The selected answer only shows the Example, but it is not a normative wording. And the normative wording in front of the Example doesn't guarantee that the whole `T(T(T()))` collapses into `()` or that the copy/move constructor is not selected by overload resolution.

Comment: BTW, that wording doesn't even seem apply to your case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't make an ill-formed program build. It gets rid of the reference to the deleted function entirely. The appropriate wording in the proposal is here:

[dcl.init] bullet 17.6

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified
>   version of the source type is the same class as the class of the
>   destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the
>   destination object. [ Example: T x = T(T(T())); calls the T default
>   constructor to initialize x. ]

The example further strengthens this. Since it indicates the whole expression must collapse into a single default construction.

The thing to note is that the deleted function is never odr-used when the copies are elided due to value categories, so the program is **not** referring to it.

This is an important distinction, since the *other* form of copy elision still odr-uses the copy c'tor, as described here:

[basic.def.odr]/3

> ... A constructor selected to copy or move an object of class type is
>   odr-used even if the call is actually elided by the implementation
>   ([class.copy] ...

[class.copy] describes the other form of permissible (but not mandatory) copy-elision. Which, if we demonstrate with your class:

```
Thing foo() {
    Thing t;
    return t; // Can be elided according to [class.copy.elision] still odr-used
}
```

Should make the program ill-formed. [And GCC complains about it as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27324aa18431270f).

---

And by the way. If you think the previous example in the online compiler is a magicians trick, and GCC complains because it needs to *call* the move c'tor. [Have a look at what happens when we supply a definition](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31cd3da6508482d5).

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply. I think the next (17.6.2) bullet is actually more interesting: "Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered."That is rvalue reference constructors are not considered when passing appropriate prvalue, so program seem to stay well-formed because deleted constructor was not considered. But it seems to be somewhat inconsistent with copy/move elision section requirement.

Comment: @VTT - The copy/move elision section is about a different thing, really. I think it's pertinent to note that while the proposal is colloquially for "mandatory copy/move elision", it uses the term "temporary materialization" instead. So essentially, it doesn't define a copy that *may* be elided. It simply delays the initialization to as late a stage as possible, so there is in fact no need for a copy. That's how the magic happens.

Comment: The problem is that with deleted / not accessible constructors not considered this delayed initialization makes it possible to [pass objects around by value ultimately leading to object construction in places that would be otherwise prohibited to do so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e545a9ced7f47fdb). I can imagine some benefits (for example class encapsulating `mutex` and having a method directly returning `lock_guard` instead of returning a reference to `mutex` to construct `lock_guard` on the user side). But it still feels wrong.

Comment: @VTT - I get why it feels wrong. It's kind of a major paradigm shift. But as you said, it also as many benefits.

Comment: @VTT: You're not passing objects around. You are passing prvalues around, which are *explicitly* not objects yet. [That's the trick that makes guaranteed elision work. A prvalue is not an object yet. It is an *initializer* for an object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043319/how-does-guaranteed-copy-elision-work/38043447#38043447) By redefining the meaning of prvalues, you remove the operations that would have been elided.

Comment: _The appropriate wording in the proposal is here_ The initializer is not a prvalue expression but braced list, how is it appropriate?